How to find Datasource in Crystal reports
I am new to Crystal Reports and have 0 knowledge to that, I am trying to find a data source on the Crystal Report.
I want to know exactly what table or stored procedure it is using to fetch data, pretty confused over here.
Thank You.

Select the menu option of Database, Database Expert...
To see the data source properties, select the menu option of
Database, Set DataSource Location...
